# Dynamically translate posixGroup to groupOfNames in slapd (Apple Open Directory)

Tags: ldap, mac-osx-server, opendirectory

I'm setting up an application to authenticate to Open Directory using LDAP.

Open Directory stores groups in RFC 2307 posixGroups format, like this:

```
cn: mygroup
objectClass: top
objectClass: apple-group
objectClass: posixGroup
apple-group-memberguid: AA7B69F2-84E1-4ED3-AEC6-25AD976DB1C7
memberUid: noa
```

But the application expects groups to be in the style of LDAP Core Schema groupOfNames format, like this:

```
cn: mygroup
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfNames
member: uid=noa,cn=users,dc=myserver,dc=example,dc=private
```

In other words, the directory server is providing an unqualified uid, whereas the application requires a DN.

How can I configure slapd either to:

1. Dynamically provide an entity that looks like `groupOfNames` (duplicated from above):

   ```
   cn: mygroup
   objectClass: top
   objectClass: groupOfNames
   member: uid=noa,cn=users,dc=myserver,dc=example,dc=private
   ```
2. Or dynamically emit extra attributes with the DNs of group members, like this:

   ```
   cn: mygroup
   objectClass: top
   objectClass: apple-group
   objectClass: posixGroup
   apple-group-memberguid: AA7B69F2-84E1-4ED3-AEC6-25AD976DB1C7
   memberUid: noa
   memberDn: uid=noa,cn=users,dc=myserver,dc=example,dc=private
   ```

It seems like an OpenLDAP overlay can do this, but I'm looking for help with the details.

(The application is BusinessObjects Crystal Reports Server. Support says they don't support OpenLDAP, but after researching the directory servers they *do* support, I believe this should work with the help of some translation. I can configure the class and attributes names, but to reiterate, the group must provide members using a DN, not a UID.)